# Can't login Fx5200

Tags: intel

Well, I have a problem when try to login into my session of Elementary OS and have connected the video card Nvidia Fx5200, but I need the video card because if I disconnect the video card, the OS run very slow and I can't use.

I try to login to my session when the video card is disconnected, and I can login correctly!

My PC is:

> Intel Pentium 4 3.0 ghz
>
> Nvidia Fx5200 256mb
>
> HDD 500gb
>
> OS: Elementary Freya stable 0.3.1

Well, I think this is all

Please How I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't expect ancient hardware to work with elementary.What is your integrated graphics

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you installed elementary os it configured x-windows to use your on board graphics card, with the Nvidia connected its still trying to use driver from the on board graphics card.

Connect the nvidia card and start up
At the log in screen, don't log in.
Press Ctrl+alt+f2
Log in with your username and password in the text terminal. Then run:

sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg

Reboot, enjoy. PS I would use the nouveau driver for that card, it will already be installed and is an open source driver for Nvidia cards with KMS supported automatically. You do not have to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your Nvidia Fx5200 is nearly 12 years **old** now.Refer [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_FX_series#Hardware_refreshes_and_diversification). It's not supported by the Nvidia current driver anymore.

Use the 173.x branch of the driver.Refer [here](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-ia32-173.14.36-driver.html)

Comment: Yeah I know, but my laptop is dead and I back to go to my old pc :(

How I install this if I can't log? :S

Comment: use live usb and use advanced options to repair system...I can't give exact steps,but have a try,please let me know what has happened  =)

Comment: How I do that? haha sorry I'm noob

Comment: how you installed elementary OS?

Comment: No, elementary OS are installed; how I install the driver of Nvidia from live usb!

Comment: Sorry...I mean , you said unable to login , for that I suggested live usb not to install nvidia

Comment: Yeah, but I can't login when the video card are connected :S

Comment: Is there any error message while logging in with video card?

Comment: No, only show me lines distorted, with the wallpaper when I try, and send me back to the log screen; I try once again and the result is the same!